# edit path for nested resource throws error missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I've viewed several different similar SO posts and tried the solutions, but none are working for me, and I've been stuck on this for a few days now. I think there may be something else wrong with my application causing this problem.

Problem:
I need to make a link to edit a contact's address. I know the route requires both IDs, but I cannot figure out why the variables I am providing fail to give the address id like they do in the destroy method link. It may be something wrong with this piece:
**<%= link_to 'Edit Address', edit_contact_address_path(address.contact, address) %>**
or maybe something in one of my controller's edit methods. I can't figure it out. I appreciate any help. Apologies for any foolish mistakes, I'm very new to this.

Error:

```
Started GET "/contacts/16/" for ::1 at 2020-09-20 14:02:46 +0200
Processing by ContactsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
  Contact Load (13.8ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:8:in `show'
  Rendering contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Address Load (6.3ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."contact_id" = $1  [["contact_id", 16]]
  ↳ app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:21
  Rendered contacts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.3ms | Allocations: 2127)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 20.4ms | Allocations: 3488)

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :contact_id=>"16", :controller=>"addresses", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]):
    28:       <td><%= address.zip %></td>
    29:       <td><%= address.state %></td>
    30:       <td><%= address.country %></td>
    31:       <td><%= link_to 'Edit Address', edit_contact_address_path(address.contact, address) %></td>
    32:       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy Address', [address.contact, address],
    33:                method: :delete,
    34:                data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  
app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:31
app/views/contacts/show.html.erb:21
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts do
    resources :addresses
  end
  root to: 'welcome#index'
end
```

models/address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  validates :street, :town, :zip, :country, presence: true
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

models/contact.rb

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
  validates :first_name, presence: true
  validates :last_name, presence: true
end
```

[views/contacts/show.html/erb](https://github.com/DStringer18/address_book/blob/master/app/views/contacts/show.html.erb)

```
[...excerpt...]
<% if @contact.addresses.any? %>
<h2>Addresses</h2>
  <% @contact.addresses.each do |address| %>
  <% debug address.id %>
  <table>
  <tr>
      <td><%= address.id %></td>
      <td><%= address.street %></td>
      <td><%= address.town %></td>
      <td><%= address.zip %></td>
      <td><%= address.state %></td>
      <td><%= address.country %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit Address', edit_contact_address_path(address.contact, address) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy Address', [address.contact, address],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

[controllers/contacts_controller.rb](https://github.com/DStringer18/address_book/blob/master/app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb)

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
[...excerpt...]

  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @address = @contact.addresses.new
  end
```

[controllers/addresses_controller.rb](https://github.com/DStringer18/address_book/blob/master/app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb)

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController
[...excerpt...]

  def new
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
    @address = Address.new
  end
  
  def edit
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
    @address = @contact.addresses.find(params[:id])
  end
```

rake routes:

```
contact_addresses GET    /contacts/:contact_id/addresses(.:format)                                                addresses#index
                                      POST   /contacts/:contact_id/addresses(.:format)                                                addresses#create
                  new_contact_address GET    /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/new(.:format)                                            addresses#new
                 edit_contact_address GET    /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/:id/edit(.:format)                                       addresses#edit
                      contact_address GET    /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                            addresses#show
                                      PATCH  /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                            addresses#update
                                      PUT    /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                            addresses#update
                                      DELETE /contacts/:contact_id/addresses/:id(.:format)                                            addresses#destroy
                             contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)                                                                      contacts#index
                                      POST   /contacts(.:format)                                                                      contacts#create
                          new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)                                                                  contacts#new
                         edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             contacts#edit
                              contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)                                                                  contacts#show
                                      PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)                                                                  contacts#update
                                      PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)                                                                  contacts#update
                                      DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error starts here:

```rb
  def show
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @address = @contact.addresses.new
  end
```

Calling `@contact.addresses.new` creates a new `Address` model tied to your `@contact`. The brand new `Address` **does not yet have an ID**. You are doing this even if the `@contact` already has addresses saved. So, when you start your iteration:

```rb
<% @contact.addresses.each do |address| %>
```

Once it hits that unsaved `Address`, it will create a link with a `nil` ID; clicking that will not work.

Removing the unused `@address = @contact.addresses.new` line will make the page work, though you won't have any addresses in the table yet. If you're trying to test, you can always add a link to that contact page to `new_contact_address_path(@contact)` to make a new one!

Update: To continue using `@address` for a form on the page, you can create it from the perspective of the `Address`:

```rb
@address = Address.new(contact: @contact)
```

That will assign the new `@address` your current `@contact` to start with, but it will NOT modify the `@contact`'s list of addresses, which is what  you want here.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense! Unfortunately, I need that line of code to make my address form partial function: <%= form_with model: [ contact, address ] do |form| %>

If I remove it, I get the error, "undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass"

Would you be able to help with another way of defining @address in the show method without breaking the form? I'm passing in the variable as a local variable in the contacts/show.html.erb file and in the addresses/edit.html.erb

Comment: Thank you so much! You've really helped me so much after days of struggle. I'm off to the next error :)

Answer (score 0):

As You're using a loop:

`<% @contact.addresses.each do |address| %>` I guess one of the `address` is missing the `id` value.

Try to check in the rails console: `Contact.find(16).addresses.pluck(:id)`. I'm sure you'll find a `nil` value in the result array.